# Any Facebook component doesn't work on Wordpress website after update. Why?

Tags: facebook, updates

I have a problem after updating plugins and `Wordpress`. All my Facebook widgets that I have been using disappeared. In code I see:

```
    <fb:like href='http://facebook.com/...' send='false' layout='standard' show_faces='false' width='200' height='65' action='like' colorscheme='light' font='lucida grande'></fb:like>
```

and the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({"appId":"...","channelUrl":"http:\/\/...\/?sfc-channel-file=1","status":true,"cookie":true,"xfbml":true,"oauth":true});
  };
 (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));     
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

        request = true;

        b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
        b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
    }());
</script>
```

Is there anything missing? What could be changed during update?
[If you need a full code.](http://www.comfortzg.com/~konrad)

Answer (score 1):

Your theme and some plugins are loading older and incorrect versions of jQuery. Update your themes and/or plugins to use the jQuery components included in WordPress itself. WordPress includes up-to-date versions of these components, themes and plugins should not load their own.