# javascript is not working on Event Submission?

Tags: jquery, javascript, events

I am using [Events Manager Plugin](http://wp-events-plugin.com/)

Javascript is not working on **Submit Events** Page .
I found the reason behind this , that was, I have written a line of code in functions.php to call jquery file.

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery-1.7.2',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');`

When I remove this line of code then javascripts start working fine on Event Submission Page but this file is important for me because I am using this file at many places too so I can not remove this. For Example I have a line of code which generates error.Line is :

`var p_option = $('input[@name="p_option"]:checked').val();` .

This line is written in **'wordpress_1/wp-content/themes/my-theme/sidebar.php'**

I also asked this question on plugin support but no reply from there.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You're enqueuing a specific version of jquery. It's better to enqueue the version that comes with WP, like this: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in a function run by the hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: @LeaCohen, I think this could go straight as [an Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83546/12615)... ;)

Comment: @LeaCohen When I am using **wp_enqueue_script('jquery');** then it is showing error $ is not a function means javascript is not working. Let me tell you I am writing this in my **custom theme's function.php** file

Comment: @brasofilo Please tell me which plugin to update..

Comment: Bhuvnesh, you are not providing enough details for a proper Answer... What do you mean with **"I am using this file at many places so I can not remove this"** ? Do you have your own jQuery functions somewhere? Where? Please, **[edit]** your Question and add relevant information.

Comment: @brasofilo I have a line of code which generates error line is : `p_option = $('input[@name="p_option"]:checked').val();`. This line is written in **'wordpress_1/wp-content/themes/my-theme/sidebar.php'**

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta - WordPress jQuery is in [noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers), you must use `jQuery` as object reference, not `$`.

Comment: @Milo I tried it but showing following error : `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[@name="p_option"]:checked`

Comment: I don't think `@name` selector is valid any more since jQuery 1.3

Comment: @Milo **@name** is working fine when I am using jquery 1.7.2 in **functions.php** as `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-1.7.2',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');`

Comment: well that's odd, I question whether that jQuery file is actually version 1.7.2., old xpath @ selectors are no longer supported and should be updated. anyway, just remove the `@`

Comment: @Milo after removing **@** error is **jquery** is not defined.

Comment: `jQuery`, not `jquery`. please read the page I linked above carefully. update your question with your current code.

Comment: @Milo Yes it was my mistake. Now it's solved thanx for help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're enqueuing a specific version of jQuery. It's better to enqueue the version that comes with WP, like this: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in a function run by the hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: When I am using **wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ** then it is showing error **$** is not a function means javascript is not working. Let me tell you I am writing this in my **custom theme's function.php** file so is it right way to add **jquery** file.

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta, As written in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers), and as Milo said in one of the comments to your question, WP runs jQuery in no-conflict mode, which means that the $ shortcut is not available and the longer jQuery is used. I suggest you read a little about it int the codex, in the link I gave.

Comment: I did it. I tried **jquery** too but not working. Please read our comments conversation.